# How can I get all information about specific user in ubuntu using bash ?

Tags: linux, bash

Right now I have this code, that gives me only name, but I want to get name and other information from file /etc/passwd,

```
#!/bin/bash

user=$1; 
grep home /etc/passwd | grep $user | cut -d: -f1;
```

I would like to get the full line, Not only my name.

Comment: *get all information about specific user* and `cut -d: -f1` are in complete contradiction

Comment: Take a look at awk: `awk -F : -v u="$user" '$1 == u {print $1,$5,$6,$7}' /etc/passwd`

Comment: What do you mean by "other information" and what do you intend to do with it?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Answer (score 2):

Here is all the info on the *current* user.  Note that because `$USER` is just a variable, it can be changed whereas the `id` command gives the actual user.

```
myuser@PC:~$ getent passwd $(id -u)
myuser:x:1000:1000:"",,,:/home/myuser:/bin/bash
myuser@PC:~$ export USER=root
myuser@PC:~$ getent passwd $USER
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Comment: You could also use the readonly variable `EUID` instead of calling `id`, although `id` will work in any shell.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `finger` command.  You may need to install it.